# How to parse trace output using ABI & web3?

Tags: json-rpc, python, openethereum, transaction-trace

I am pulling a trace from a Parity node using the JSONRPC API. It looks like this:

```py
print(trace)
{
    'action': {
        'callType': 'staticcall',
        'from': '0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'gas': '0x1ad02e',
        'input': '0x2f58b80d',
        'to': '0xZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
        'value': '0x0'
    },
    'result': {'gasUsed': '0x501', 'output': '0x000000000000000000000000082b0ca59f2122c94e5f57db0085907fa9584ba6'},
    'subtraces': 0,
    'traceAddress': [0, 0],
    'type': 'call'
}
```

I can decode the `input` using the ABI from the `to` address, but this doesn't seem to work for the `result.output` field.

```py
# this works
print(contract.decode_function_input(trace['action']['input']))
(<Function balanceOf(address)>, {'': '0xYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'})

# this does not
print(contract.decode_function_input(trace['result']['output']))
*** ValueError: Could not find any function with matching selector
```

Is the `output` encoded in a different way, maybe one that isn't tied to the ABI for the input?

I am not able to find documentation on how to decode it. I also tried using `decode_function_input()` for the ABI it calls, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Any updates on this? @lollercoaster were you able to find any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code for

```
contract.decode_function_input
```

Your contract object is of the token in question or of the router?
E.g. on BSC (BinanceSmartChain), you need to use the PancakeSwapRouter Version2 address (I know because I am decoding transaction.input data there on daily basis).